# How to add multiple commands in series in "Execute Windows Batch Command" in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, ant

I have a requirement where I need to run certain commands in series in order to build my project. Can I have give all the commands together in series in Jenkins? How am I supposed to do that. If I give it like as shown below :

[image]

How can give the commands so that it will execute one after the other. Please help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it's better to execute separate build steps, like:

- Windows batch step: env.bat
- Ant build step: ant build ...
- Windows batch step: force-db.bat

Comment: Are there any steps to execute it in series?

Comment: If you have to mix Windows batch + Ant for example, I don't think so.
If you are using only Windows batch commands for example, you can launch all of them in the same build step.

Comment: How Am I supposed to add ant builds in Jenkins?

Comment: When you add a build step, you can select "Invoke Ant". In the Jenkins general settings, you have to declare your Ant installation.

Comment: I'll try. Thank you.

Comment: OK, if it works, don't forget to vote for my answer ;)

Answer (score 10):

You can run a series of commands in windows command prompt using & operator.

So below will work from a single line command

**env.bat & ant & forced-db.bat**

Comment: This works as expected